# SCIP separators using Java

Tags: java, scip

I am currently working with SCIP by implementing in Java using the Java Native Interface. I implemented a basic Covering Set Problem and the solver works great. My next step is to generate cutting planes by adding my own separators. I already found something on the [SCIP page](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/SEPA.php) but I don't know how to adapt the instructions using Java and the Java Native Interface. Thanks for every answer...

Comment: I don't know exactly how the JNI works but you may need to write your new separator in C, update the interface accordingly and then call it from Java.

Comment: Why not use Clojure and write in LISP?